# How to specify vendor id while installing ubuntu touch

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, android, udev

I am trying to install Ubuntu Touch on my YU Yuphoria
(guided by  http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/).

When I tried to list devices on fastboot before unlocking the bootloader; list was empty.But device was listed for adb devices.Still I unlocked device  specifying vendor id as

```
sudo fastboot -i 0x2a96 oem unlock
```

After that,when I am trying to install ubuntu touch  using command :

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
```

it is showing like  *Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting*
and it stuck there !! . I think vendor id needs to specified in that command too... How to specify device id in last command??

Note:Already added vendor id in etc /udev/rules.d/51-android.rules and restarted using below command:

```
sudo sh -c "(udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger --action=change)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily alias the fastboot command and try.

In shell, enter the command

```
alias fastboot='fastboot -i 0x2a96'
```

You can add the same line to your `.bashrc` and restart the shell.

After flashing is done, revert the bashrc changes, else it affects other devices not getting recognised.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get pass through this. Apparently my fastboot was too old on my Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

I downloaded the newest android SDK from it's website. Then I moved the fastboot from /usr/bin then placed the fastboot from the downloaded SDK to /usr/bin.

```
mv /usr/bin/fastboot /usr/bin/fastboot1
ln -s /home/nayar/sdk/platform-tools/fastboot /usr/bin/fastboot
```